# How do I pass an additional variable to function theme_item_list

Tags: theming

I need an additional variable to be available to the function `theme_item_list`. How do I correcly pass my variable so that I can alter the function like so:

```
function theme_item_list($variables) {
  $items = $variables['items'];
  $title = $variables['title'];
  $type = $variables['type'];
  $attributes = $variables['attributes'];
  $MY_VAR = $variables['MY_VAR'];
```

Here is my render array:

```
  $node->content['list'] = array(
    '#theme' => 'item_list',
    '#items' => $items,
    '#weight' => 2,
    '#prefix' => '<div id="list">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  );
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement [`hook_theme_registry_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_theme_registry_alter/7) to let Drupal know about the new var:

```
function MYTHEME_theme_registry_alter(&$registry) {
  $registry['item_list']['variables']['MY_VAR'] = NULL;
}
```

Then override the theme function:

```
function MYTHEME_item_list($vars) {
  // Copy/change original theme_item_list as required.
  // $vars['MY_VAR'] is available as long as it has been passed in.
}
```

And just make sure you pass the var in your render array:

```
$node->content['list'] = array(
  '#theme' => 'item_list',
  '#items' => $items,
  '#weight' => 2,
  '#prefix' => '<div id="list">',
  '#suffix' => '</div>',
  '#MY_VAR' => 'foo',
);
```

Comment: Thanks. It was the `hook_theme_registry_alter` nugget I was missing.